# How to create Nested subfolder in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I need to create a structure like below inside Document directory.

Document -> Folder -> subFolder1 -> subFolder2 -> subFolder3 ----- subFolderN dynamically and show them in a UITableViewController.

Is it possible in iOS. Please help

Comment: This has been asked & answered million times. Why don't you search...

Comment: I have searched for last 2 days but didn't get any satisfactory answer as i required.

Comment: if you know then please provide some links

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtPath%3awithIntermediateDirectories%3aattributes%3aerror%3a) method of [`NSFileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Pass `YES` to `withIntermediateDirectories` and you can create an entire subtree with one call.